# How to authenticate POP3 with Gmail?

Tags: authentication, pop3

I'm trying to figure out how to send my credentials to Gmail. [RFC5034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5034) gives an example

```
S: IMPLEMENTATION BlurdyBlurp POP3 server
S: .
C: AUTH PLAIN dGVzdAB0ZXN0AHRlc3Q=
S: +OK Maildrop locked and ready
```

and the base64 encoded string decodes to test\0test\0test where \0 is null character.

However, if I send a base64 encoded string like that username\0user@gmail.com\0password, then I get an error message like this

```
-ERR [SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem.  Please try again later. df2mb862702032iec
```

So, these are the combinations I've tried with their outcomes:

```
user\0password => -ERR invalid SASL argument 42mb45977297otf
user@gmail.com\0password => -ERR invalid SASL argument uz3mb206121874obc
\0user@gmail.com\0password =>  -ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.
\0user\0password => -ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.
name\0user@gmail.com\0password => -ERR [SYS/TEMP] Temporary system problem.  Please try again later. df2mb862702032iec
\0name\0user@gmail.com\0password => -ERR invalid SASL argument h184mb244881255oib
```

So, it looks like it should be \0user@gmail.com\0password but if I base64 encode my email and password like this:

```
echo -ne '\0user@gmail.com\0password' | base64
```

My username and password are still rejected.

So, can someone confirm the correct method of base64 encoding?  Oh, and I have Pop mail activated in my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is that there's a bug with Gmail.  Even though with pop3 enabled on my account (of 15Gb of email), it doesn't recognise my credentials.

I have another email account with my own domain on gmail with very little mail and using the base64 version of

```
\0user@domain.com\0password
```

works just fine where \0 represents the null character.

Comment: I tried user/pass initially and that had the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you hit a hit an issue.  Does it work with IMAP?

Comment: I haven't tried imap yet ... I'm writing my own pop3 handlers, and imap will be next!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable "less secure apps" in your GMail settings:

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1